# Footer в опере, мозилле и гугле немного наезжает на рамку

Tags: html, css

Footer (подвал)  в опере, мозилле и гугле немного (2-3пикселя) наезжает на рамку дива-контейнера. В IE все отлично. Хотя и не очень заметно, но почему так происходит? Вроде див footer находится внутри. С другими блоками все нормально.У меня див контейнер и три дива в нем: Header, Content, Footer. Ширина фиксированная у всех по 850 пикселей.Вот код css:

```
body{
    background:#CFF;
    width:auto;
    padding-left:50%;
    margin:0;   
}                             
#main{
width:850px;
border:10px groove #99F ;
background:#FEFEFE;
margin-left:-425px;
padding:0;
}
#header1{
background-image: url(images/header1.jpg);
width:850px;
height:128px;                                                      
background-repeat:no-repeat;             
}
#glav{
float:left;
width:auto;
margin-left:20px;
font:italic 18px bolder Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;     
}

#menu{
float:left;
width:auto;
clear:left;
margin-left:20px;
font:italic 18px bolder Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#ist{
float:left;
width:auto;
clear:left;
margin-left:20px;
font:italic 18px bolder Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#content{
width:auto;
margin-left:50px;
margin-right:50px;
text-align: justify;
}
p{
  text-indent:2em;
}
#footer{
    background-image: url(images/footer.jpg);
    width:850px;
    height:30px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-top:500px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align:right; 
  padding-right:10px;
  padding-top:5px;
}
```

И когда без отступов вокруг текста - все нормально,но стоит добавить отступы - так все съезжает, а без отступов некрасиво, текст жмется кверху и вправо.

Comment: Так аонятнее. Но лучше еще кусок верстки, если мой ответ не поможет:

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Достаточно указать ширину только для #main. В Header, Content, Footer ширину указывать не обязательно (они растянуться на ширину родителя).

Общая ширина элемента суммируется из заданной ширины и его внутреннего отступа. Так как ширина чётко задана (850) и есть отступ (5) - общая ширина элемента = 855 (вместо нужных 850). Это правило также касается высоты элемента. Для решения подобных проблем, не указывайте ширину элемента и поставьте свойство display: block; (для не блочных элементов), тогда общая ширина элемента будет всегда 100% ширины родителя.

```
#footer{
    background-image: url(images/footer.jpg);
    height:30px;
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    margin-top:500px;
    font-size: 9px;
    text-align:right; 
    padding-right:10px;
    padding-top:5px;
}
```

**PS:** По поводу css reset сказано верно. Для достижения кроссбраузерности, его использование обязательно.

Answer (score 1):

Есть такая штука - [CSS RESET](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/), которая обнуляет все что только возможно. 
Вот с нее и надо начинать лепить верстку.
Если не поможет - [Условные комментарии](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/condcom.html) вам в помощь.

P.S. вопрос слишком общий, поэтому и ответ общий. Если будет конкретный кусок, можно будет разбираться

UPD:
начать с того, что у футера у вас есть padding. Он автоматически увеличивает ширину на свою величину:

```
width: 200px;
padding: 30px;
```

общая ширина будет - 260px: ширина + 2 паддинга.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую.